# SSL error connecting to Google Firestore in Python

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There are different function that causes the error while connecting to Firestore database.

This is an example:

```
def experiments():
id_token = request.headers['Authorization'].split()[1]
try:
    decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
    uid = decoded_token['uid']

    ref = firestore.client().collection('users').document(uid).get()
    user = ref.to_dict()['email']
    #experiments = {}
    experiments = get_experiments_per_user(user)
    return jsonify(experiments)
except auth.ExpiredIdTokenError:
    print("TOKEN EXPIRED!!")
    return "Token expired", 400
```

Error:

```
E0324 19:13:31.607209998    6992 ssl_transport_security.cc:510] Corruption detected.
E0324 19:13:31.607283755    6992 ssl_transport_security.cc:486] error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT
E0324 19:13:31.607299533    6992 ssl_transport_security.cc:486] error:1000008b:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:DECRYPTION_FAILED_OR_BAD_RECORD_MAC
E0324 19:13:31.607310259    6992 secure_endpoint.cc:208]     Decryption error: TSI_DATA_CORRUPTED
E0324 19:13:31.607388611    6992 ssl_transport_security.cc:537] SSL_write failed with error SSL_ERROR_SSL.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 73, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 923, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 826, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.UNKNOWN
    details = "Stream removed"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1616609611.607356500","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:216.58.209.42:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1067,"grpc_message":"Stream removed","grpc_status":2}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "./flask_server.py", line 163, in experiments
    ref = firestore.client().collection('users').document(uid).get()
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/document.py", line 361, in get
    document_pb = firestore_api.get_document(
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/firestore_v1/services/firestore/client.py", line 388, in get_document
    response = rpc(request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata,)
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 145, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 281, in retry_wrapped_func
    return retry_target(
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/retry.py", line 184, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "/home/developer/spir-back-end/backendvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 75, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.Unknown: None Stream removed
```

How you can see, the instruction  `ref = firestore.client().collection('users').document(uid).get()` is throwing the exception.

One clarification: this error never occured on development environment, but started to occur on production environment on another computer with different O.S and different network. Could the problem be caused from it?

Comment: Same error - see: https://github.com/googleapis/python-firestore/issues/512

Answer (score 0):

Are you using proper headers? Some websites detect and block web scrapers. You can add headers like this:

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; VOG-L29) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.105 Mobile Safari/537.36 OPR/62.3.3146.57763'}
```

Comment: Where should I add this headers?

Comment: You can then add them in the initial request so it becomes ```r = requests.post('url, headers=headers')```

Comment: The problem is from my back-end to google firestore, how adding user agent can help me?